# Group values by keys in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, group-by

What I have:

```
d = {datetime.date(2013, 1, 1): {'15169': 2, '56203': 5, '2519': 3, '18144': 3, '9737': 4},
datetime.date(2014, 1, 1): {'15169': 5, '56203': 3, '2519': 2, '18144': 1, '9737': 0}}
```

What I want:

```
{15169:[2,5], 56203:[5,3], 2519:[3,2], 18144:[3,1], 9737:[4,0]}
```

Is there any straight-forward method to achieve this?
Tried multiple ways but looks like there's not any straight-forward method.

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be straightforward or not.

Comment: I would consider it straightforward to iterate over the dictionaries in `d` and append the contained values to the corresponding lists in the result dictionary.

Comment: "Tried multiple ways but looks like there's not any straight-forward method." What ways did you try? Why did you think they are "not straight-forward"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ans = {}
[[ans.setdefault(k, []).append(v) for k, v in x.items()] for x in d.values()]
ans
# {'15169': [2, 5],
#  '56203': [5, 3],
#  '2519': [3, 2],
#  '18144': [3, 1],
#  '9737': [4, 0]}
```

Or using pandas

```
pd.DataFrame(d).apply(list, axis=1).to_dict()
# {'15169': [2, 5],
#  '56203': [5, 3],
#  '2519': [3, 2],
#  '18144': [3, 1],
#  '9737': [4, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

as straightforward as I can imagine, use `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

out = defaultdict(list)

for x in d.values():
    for k,v in x.items():
        out[k].append(v)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'15169': [2, 5],
             '56203': [5, 3],
             '2519': [3, 2],
             '18144': [3, 1],
             '9737': [4, 0]})
```